# Csvhelper set index dynamically to different csv

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I receive different CSV without header (we agreed about the content but not the format) from different customers, and I'm trying to build a generic class that can parse it hard coupling it with CSVHelper (who knows if tomorrow it is not supported anymore).
For example the first customer send a CSV as
"Name;Lastname;Age;Birthplace", the second customer send it as "Birthplace;Lastname;Firstname;Age", and another customer sends "Firstname;Lastname". I create a custom attribute in which I put the index expected, and at runtime I would like to add the IndexAttribute from CsvHelper.

```
partial class CustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
}

public class PersonCustomer1 : IPerson
{
    [CustomAttribute(Index = 0)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [CustomAttribute(Index = 1)]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [CustomAttribute(Index = 3)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class PersonCustomer2 : IPerson
{
    [CustomAttribute(Index = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [CustomAttribute(Index = 1)]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [CustomAttribute(Index = 0)]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [CustomAttribute(Index = 3)]
    public int Gender { get; set; }
}
```

The generic converter is build as

```
public class ConverterCsv<T>
{

    public IEnumerable<T> Convert(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> records = new List<T>();
        using (var reader = fileInfo.OpenText())
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CsvGenericMap<T>>();
            records = csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
        }

        return records;
    }
}

public sealed class CsvGenericMap<T> : ClassMap<T>
{
    public CsvGenericMap()
    {
        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            var attribute = property?.GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttribute>();
          //what now? How should I inject the CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Index attribute?
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect that any csv, with its custom attribute set, will fill the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
public sealed class CsvGenericMap<T> : ClassMap<T>
{
    public CsvGenericMap()
    {
        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            var attribute = property?.GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttribute>();

            Map(typeof(T), property).Index(attribute.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the reply. I want to avoid to use CSVHelper attribute directly on these classes, I would like to inject it at runtime from the custom attribute created. I am trying to avoid to hard coupling the Person class to CSVHelper.